# PHP navigation with multiple GET variables

Tags: php, variables, navigation, get

I'm bashing my head for weeks trying to find the ideal way to do php navigation.

(Ideal = extremely flexible + 100% SEO friendly).

Where I got thus far:

With help of .htaccess, any number of variables is passed to php as an array.
Meaning, this:

www.example.com/somepage/subpage/some-parameters-too

will give me an array with 3 strings

'somepage'
'subpage'
'some-parameters-too'

Now...this works nicely, but if I'm here:

www.example.com/somepage/

and click 'home' in my menu, it practically calls a non-existing page

www.example.com/somepage/home

Now...

I know that if my anchor tag instead of "home" contained "http://www.example.com/home",
that would work, but I've read (here on site somewhere) that it's both ineffective and
insecure (and disabled by many hosts - i know it's disabled by default on my localhost)

So - how to do this?

I see links on stackoverflow showing as absolute urls, where am I making a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `<base>` element to specify from which url must start relative paths.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp